# OMEN by HP Laptop 15-dh0xxx, Realtek ALC285, Ubuntu 20.04 LTS - Microphone doesn't work

Tags: 20.04, pulseaudio, alsa, hp, microphone

The sounds and microphone didn't work immediately after installing the Ubuntu 20.04.
There was only "Dummy output" in the output device list. The input device list was empty.

After I added lines below to `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

```
options snd-hda-intel model=clevo-p950
options snd-hda-intel model=generic
options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0
options snd-hda-intel model=laptop-dmic
options snd-hda-intel probe_mask=1
```

- "Speakers - Built-in Audio" - appeared (Output Device)
- "Microphone - Built-in Audio" - appeared (Input Device)

I can hear sounds now, **but the microphone doesn't work**.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug :[Microphone not working in Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1840725)

What worked for me was the steps indicated in the [post #63](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-driver/+bug/1840725/comments/63):

Execute `arecord -l`.

You will get something similar to this :

```
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC3254 Analog [ALC3254 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Take note of the `Subdevices 1/1` line.

Now edit `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` as sudo. Remove the lines you added and put these 2 instead:

```
options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0
options snd-hda-intel index=XXXX model=laptop-dmic
```

where XXXX is either :

- `0` if you had `Subdevices : 0/1`
- `1` if you had `Subdevices : 1/1`

Then save and reboot.

The bug behaves differently for different hardware so you may or may not need `options snd-hda-intel dmic_detect=0`. For some people it disabled sound but it is the opposite for me, sound does not work if I comment this line out.

If it still does not work I recommend reading the whole launchpad discussion because the different fixes had varying success depending on hardware and OS version.

I hope I helped.