# Alsamixer - Mic Off

Tags: pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

I've had this problem for X years and never found a solution the workaround has been to use Signal on my mobile and not Skype. But finally, now that I want to digitise old band practises on DAT and MiniDisc I have no choice but to use the analogue mic input.

I've narrowed down the problem to the mics being marked [off] in Alsa mixer and being displayed as [unplugged] in sounds settings.
I have also have a "rear mic", which appears to be the default, I have no idea where this is or what it is, but it has never captured anything.

[Alsa Mixer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RdR5t.png)
[Pulse Audio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ou4Gq.png)
[Sound Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBV1s.png)

The external mic is plugged in and I'm trying to play a MD player into it.

Any ideas - I hope someone can give me a one liner as to how to switch those mics to on. Please.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, describe your OS version and machine name, does it have 'line in' or 'mic' jacks? Do you connect MD/DAT player headphone jack with 3.5 mm stereo cable to your `LINE IN` jack? How about using a USB DAC to capture audio, built-in LINE/MIC port is kinda cheap and never had good quality.

Comment: Thank Sadaharus:

HP Omen. 
Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

"Mic" with a 3.5mm.

I think the work around is the USB DAC - I've ordered one this morning. 
The mics being off though is still bugging me!

Comment: Is [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1287106/omen-by-hp-laptop-15-dh0xxx-realtek-alc285-ubuntu-20-04-lts-microphone-doesn) your problem? Then it was reported as a bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1892714) And I; real novice can't do about it. But it has a little [progress](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1874698)

Comment: Hi thanks for that. 
Yes many of the issues there look familiar to me. I've changed a few config files in the past but nothing seemed to fix it and I managed to disable my features. 

I think I'm just going to have to wait until "Ubuntu" works out a fix or I have to get a new laptop.

Comment: In the end I found a work around. I bought a mini usb soundcard with mic and headphones jacks. That works just fine.

Comment: Good, that is the best way, I believe.